# how to compile to ps with texstudio?

Tags: eps, texstudio, psfrag, ps

i'm a beginner in LaTeX, I'm using texstudio, but I don't know how to compile to `ps`.
I have some `.eps` files and use `psfrag` command.

Comment: If everything is configured correctly it is enough to press F2 (run `latex`), F4 (run `dvips`) and F5 (open `ps` viewer). In case of problems, adapt this solution http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95086/14757

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Options` `->` `Configure TeXStudio`. Then in the `Build` tab, under `Build and View` label, click the spanner.

Select `PDF Chain` and then `Delete`. Then, from the left pane, select `PS Chain` and `Add`. That should work.