# TeXstudio Could not start Build and View

Tags: texstudio

I'm using MikTeX 2.9 and TeXstudio 2.6.6. The path to MikTeX is correct and in "Check LaTeX installation" the process exite normally.

My problem is when I tried to "Build & View" (F1) an error message pops up with the message:

```
Could not start Build and View:PdfLaTeX:pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 interaction=nonstopmode
```

and no log file is found.

Using TeXWorks the process is done without any problems.

I like using TeXstudio, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: It should be `-interaction=nonstopmode` with a dash.

Comment: I tried with the dash. Same error.
But when i tried ps2pdf.exe "System".ps occurred a Unrecoverable error: MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05...exit code 1...and Process exited normally. Does this help?

Comment: I had this problem, because accidentally I had a filename `filename.txt` instead of the default `filename.tex`.

Answer (score 3):

I Found the answer in there [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95058/error-texstudio-could-not-start-command?rq=1)

I changed my Command line to:

```
"D:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

and it work. Thanks for the help. And a special thanks to Sigur.

Comment: So, I didn't remember my other answer. You found it!