# Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "filename".tex

Tags: errors, texstudio

[image]I'm using texstudio on Mac for a long time and everything used to work well. Suddenly, I get the following error message for every tex file I try to run:

```
Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "filename".tex
```

I believe it happened after I made some changes to my python installations on the computer. Any idea?

Comment: Can you show the "Commands" tab of your texstudio preferences?

Comment: As a test: does `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode filename` work from terminal?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use latex in the terminal. I uploaded the folder in the current directory and then past the command you suggested. I got the massege: -bash: pdflatex: command not found

Comment: I’d guess that the changes made to the python installation played with you PATH variable and you lost `/Library/TeX/texbin`. What exactly did you change?

Comment: After a few hours of searches I found the right path:  "/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I could resolve the problem by restoring to default setting using "Preferences > Command" and then the yellow buttons. See the following thread for more information.

[Error: TexStudio "Could not start command"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95058/error-texstudio-could-not-start-command/95086#95086)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reset the total setting of the texmaker .
first go on

1. option
2. setting file
3. reset setting

the all setting that you made in texmaker will reset accordingly.